# linear system equation

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given the equation $ -3x +2y =4$, write another equation that will form a linear system with: one solution, no solution and infinitely many solutions.

Infinitely many solutions:

$(-3x +2y =4) \times 3$ $\to$  $-9x +6y =12$

$y= \dfrac{3x}{2}+4$

$-9x +6y =12$

I think we have to multiply the first equation by a non-zero number right? But when I rewrite this $-9x +6y =12$ into slope-intercept form, it doesn't have the same answer as the original.

Comment: I think the slope intercept form of both eqns are the same, as they should be.  You wrote one equation into the form $y=...$ (i.e. no coefficient in front of $y$).  Do the exact same thing for the other eqn and see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to come up with a linear equation of the form $ax+by=c$ that satisfies different conditions (i.e., one solution, no solution, infinitely many solutions) when combined with $-3x+2y=4$ to make a linear system of two linear equations.

Observe the following:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}-3&2&4\\a&b&c\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&-2/3&-4/3\\a&b&c\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}1&-2/3&-4/3\\0&b-2a/3&c-4a/3\end{bmatrix}.
$$
This tells us enough to answer your question:

- **One solution:** There will be a unique solution when $b-\frac{2a}{3}\neq 0$.
- **No solution:** There will not be a solution when $b-\frac{2a}{3}=0$ and $c-\frac{4a}{3}\neq 0$.
- **Infinitely many solutions:** There will be infinitely many solutions when $b-\frac{2a}{3}=0$ and $c-\frac{4a}{3}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

For one solutions: Just plug in a pair of x,y that satisfies the given equation and also satisfies another equation that you can make up.

e.g. −3x+2y=4 : (2,5) satisfies the equation

Then (2,5) also works for x+y=7

For no solutions: Anything that when you solve the system and you get 0 = A where A is a non zero constant.

-3x+2y=5 is a quick example. Notice if I solve it by elimination, I'll get 0=1

For infinite solutions: Pretty much a constant times the original equation. This works because one of the variables becomes unrestricted.

So -6x+4y=10 works.